# Angular + Bootstrap (grid) + Component

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to develop a set of form components in Angular 8 using BootStrap but there is a strange behavior.

Following html works perfectly:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="input01" class="col-2 col-form-label">First Name</label>
    <div class="col-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input01" placeholder="First Name">
  </div>
    <label for="input01" class="col-2 col-form-label">Last Name</label>
    <div class="col-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input01" placeholder="Last Name">
  </div>
</div>
```

I can see two inputs with its labels side by side (2+4 columns for each input/label).

If I take this snipet and encapsulates it in a component:

```
<label for="input01" class="col-2 col-form-label">First Name</label>
<div class="col-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input01" placeholder="First Name">
</div>
```

And use it as following:

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <app-input-text></app-input-text>
  <app-input-text></app-input-text>
</div>
```

It seems to be shrinked.

Please note it is the same code but encapsulated in a component.

What's wrong?

PS: Here is the StackBlitz running code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g3zxg3

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bootstrap needs the .col to be a direct child of the .row. But it's not, since you have app-input-text in the middle.

Comment: Yes, you're right but how do I create multi and single column input forms if I'm stuck on this rule? I mean, if I need to create a single line field (12), I'll wrap app-input-text in a single row, if I need two inputs, I can do what I did in the sample and so on...

Comment: Use a .row **inside** the component template, with two children .col-4 and .col-8. In the parent use a .row with two children.col-6.

Comment: It works but I'll loose flexibility because my intention is to allow component user to set the width of label and input.

Comment: And why couldn't you do that? You'll actually *gain* in flexibility since your component can be used anywhere, and not only in a .row like what you have.

Comment: Actually I was looking for a way to create very flexible forms where I can hide fields (programatically) and keep layout as good as possible, so if I could just distribute components inside the form and the CSS strategy does it to me would be nice. But it is great to know that *col-* must be right after *row* class.

Comment: The best way to do that is probably to avoid using a component that doesn't bring much, but makes things way more difficult: how are you going to use ngModel or formControlName with your component? Note BTW, that both your inputs have the same ID, which is invalid.

Comment: Hello @JBNizet thank your for your advices! Surely it made me think about alternatives. As you can see below, there is an interesting solution that we should consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove wrapping tags with some work arounds. One is using directives or attribute selectors or using template injection like below:

> Component

```
export class InputTextComponent {
  @ViewChild(TemplateRef, { static: false }) template;
  constructor(private vcr: ViewContainerRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
   setTimeOut(()=> this.vcr.createEmbeddedView(this.template));
  }
}
```

> Template

```
<ng-template>
  <label for="input01" class="col-2 col-form-label">First Name</label>
    <div class="col-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input01" placeholder="First Name">
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wzs2vu)
and original source of  [work around](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18877#issuecomment-348142527)

**Edit:** As @Emilio Numazaki stated in the comments if you expose bindable properties it will cause mentioned exception to be thrown. So another workaround is needed to avoid that.

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I need! Thank you!

Comment: Heldar, there just one change I did in order to avoid ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError error: Instead of direct call to this.vcr.createEmbeddedView(this.template), I did:     Promise.resolve(null).then(() => this.vcr.createEmbeddedView(this.template));

Comment: It is important to avoid errors when you add more parameters to component. Please see the version with error: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y2wnde